# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken coming suddenly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, csrf

I have old project in Rails 5, I have to add Api and it was working fine, 3 days ago, but now it suddenly started to give me `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` I have done no changes in any controller related to web, but added few Gems includes `rspec-rails, jwt` and creating its Api, but suddenly on chrome it is giving me this error.

When I started work I tested and it was working fine, and on Safari browser it works fine. But on Chrome it gives this error. Following line is added in my application, if I disable this error goes, but I think that will make it unsecure.

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
```

I check few answers where long list that it s old issue, but I am working on many rails project and I never saw this issue! Some post direct me to use https so I also used https but issue for chrome is still there.

Any help

Comment: Is your application controller inherited from `ActionController::Base` or `ApiController::Base`. 
protect_from_forgery should be handled in ActionController::Base only, but you said you have added jwt, sounds like you are adding RESTful api functions into rails backend.

Comment: The controller ApplicationController inherited from ActionController::Base and it is all web, the another controller ApiController is perfect fine it inheritance fro applicationcontroller and is api controller so works fine, issue is Chrome give errors not other browser.

Comment: protect_from_forgery will add a hidden input into the form with a random token, maybe you want to check if this input exists in your chrome. Sounds like this hidden input was removed or broken in chrome, maybe due to some chromes plugins? Need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I originally had only a me-too comment.
But with sheer luck, I happen to know the answer.

It is not your code that changes; it's the browsers.
Please check the news related to `Same-Site` policy changes from Google.

Basically, the cookie is not working in your environment anymore because of changes in the browser, rendering the CSRF token unusable.

You have to config `Rails.application.config.session_store` in an initializer; unfortunately, there is no one-liner fixed all in this situation; it depends on the environment and situations.

Answer (score -4):

Just put the below the line in your `ApplicationController`

```rb
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: The issue is not this as in Safari it is not doing, and We need to verify CSRF token.